# Clean an in-memory database

Tags: in-memory-database, data-cleaning

I'm using Spring Batch with an HSQLDB in-memory database for Spring Batch metadata. My application needs to run continuously, so this database becomes problematic for my memory. I need a way to clean it periodically. I already thought about using a stored procedure that deletes datas according to a condition (old datas). This procedure is called periodically by a dedicated thread using Spring StoredProcedure class.

If you have alternative solutions, i'm open.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used a background task scheduled to run every X minutes. This task uses JDBC to clean the database.